# Was kann ich besser für "unerwachsen" sagen?

Tags: meaning

Welches Adjektiv kann ich für eine Person beschreiben, die sich in ihrem Alter noch unerwachsen (im positiven und negativen Sinn) verhält. Zum Beispiel: mit 50 möchte er/sie zur Party gehen oder denkt nicht tief.

Comment: NIcht mal eine ehrende Erwähnung für *unreif*?

Answer (score 5):

Da gibt es einige Adjektive, die sich aber in ihren Konnotationen gravierend unterscheiden.

> **kindlich**

kann sowohl positiv wie auch negativ besetzt verwendet werden. *Kindliche Unschuld* etwa ist meist positiv besetzt (man agiert, als hätte man - wie ein Kind - das Böse in der Welt noch nicht kennengelernt), es gibt aber auch das *kindliche Gemüt*, das durchaus als verklausulierter Ausdruck für "unerfahren/einfältig/dumm/unfähig, die Konsequenzen seines Tuns abzuschätzen" verstanden werden kann.

> **kindisch**

bedeutet zwar eigentlich dasselbe wie *kindlich*, ist aber eindeutig negativ besetzt. *Kindisch* ist jemand, der sich unangemessenerweise wie ein Kind verhält. Wer seinem Banknachbarn in der Schule den Bleistiftspitzer versteckt, ist *kindlich* (verhält sich wie ein Kind, aber eben angemessen), wer denselben Streich seinem Bürokollegen spielt, ist *kindisch* (verhält sich auch wie ein Kind, aber unangemessenerweise).

> **junggeblieben**

ist positiv konnotiert und bedeutet, daß man sich die positiven Aspekte kindlichen Verhaltens (Neugier, Arglosigkeit, ...) trotz zunehmenden Alters bewahrt hat.

> **unerwachsen**

ist das zugehörige Pendant zu *junggeblieben*, allerdings negativ besetzt - es ist ein anderes Wort für "kindisch" und hat etwa diesselbe Bedeutung und auch dieselben Konnotationen.

> **infantil**

wird in der Umgangssprache analog zu "kindisch" verwendet, kommt aber aus der medizinischen Fachsprache und bedeutet dort "aus der Kindheit stammend" bzw. "mit der Kindheit zusammenhängend" oder auch "kindartig". Wer eine "[infantile Zerebralparese](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantile_Zerebralparese)" hat, der hat eine, die aus der Kindheit herrührt und die er wohl seit damals mit sich herumträgt, ob er nun noch Kind ist oder schon erwachsen. Dahingegen kann eine "[infantile Makromastie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantile_Makromastie)" nur jemand bekommen, der tatsächlich ein Kind ist.

Answer (score 1):

Ich bin so weit von einem Experten entfernt wie möglich, möchte aber trotzdem meine Idee abgeben. Mir fiele das Wort "junggeblieben" ein.
Unter einer junggebliebenen Person kann man verstehen, dass diese nicht ihrem Alter typisch aussieht, allerdings kann man es auch auf die Gefühlswelt oder das Verhalten der Person beziehen.

Comment: "junggeblieben" kenne und verstehe ich ehrlich gesagt ausschließlich als Euphemismus für Menschen ab ~80, wenn man auf das Alter hinweisen will, ohne es durch Begriffe wie "Senior" explizit zu machen.

Answer (score 1):

Ein Adjektiv, das sowohl im positiven wie im negativen Sinn verwendet werden kann, ist im Deutschen schwierig zu finden. Aus meiner Sicht nahe dran, aber etwas hölzern:

> nicht altersgemäß

Für den negativen Kontext gibt es dagegen eine große Auswahl, auf Anhieb fallen mir ein:

> naiv, kindisch, zurückgeblieben

Answer (score 1):

Synonyme dafür gibt es viele, und je nach Kontext und Sichtweise auf das Verhalten ist das eine oder andere passend(er). Neben den in anderen Antworten schon genannten Worte und dem von Dir genannten 'unerwachsen' gibt es noch ein paar:

> unreif

> adoleszent

> pubertär oder auch prä-pubertär

Dies wird gerne auch abwertend für das Verhalten von Menschen genutzt, die eigentlich schon über diese Lebensphase hinaus sind, sich aber trotzdem (noch) so verhalten.

- heranwachsend

Dieser Begriff ist neutral. Man würde es meist als Nomen verwenden à la "Er/Sie verhält sich wie ein Heranwachsende(r)".

- halbstark

Dieser Begriff ist leicht abwertend für 'heranwachsend': "Schau Dir die an mit ihrem halbstarken Gehabe".

Answer (score 0):

Das nennt man genau so: *unerwachsen*, und zwar im übertragenen Sinn.

Das Synonymwörterbuch führt noch *minorenn* auf. Allerdings habe ich das Wort noch nie zuvor gehört oder gelesen. Zudem bedeutet es *minderjährig* und, dem Eintrag im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/minorenn) nach zu urteilen, scheint man es nicht auch in einem übertragenen Sinne für ältere Personen zu gebrauchen.